# JVM version conflict prevents Eclipse / Jetty from functioning properly

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, junit, spring-tool-suite

I'm experiencing the following conundrum while using Spring Tool Suite with the following coordinates:

```
Version: 3.9.5.RELEASE
Build Id: 201807031734
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)
```

on **MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6**.

While attempting to run any JUnit test from within STS, I'm seeing the following:

[image]

Thinking back and remembering that at some point I was able to execute JUnit tests fine on the same machine in the same STS, I recalled that recently I've removed Java 10 virtual machine from within Mac's **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/** as it happened to be a culprit causing the following error when trying to start jetty server from maven via ***mvn jetty:run***:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3119)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2268)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.secureGetDeclaredMethods(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getDeclaredMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:192)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:193)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    ... 171 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
    ... 188 more
MultiException stack 4 of 4
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbStringReaderProvider$RootElementProvider
    contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@499445d2
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=126
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1532556857
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:689)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:458)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2205)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1407)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1332)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1321)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getProviders(Providers.java:187)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverterFactory.<init>(ParamConverterFactory.java:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:692)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:228)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:692)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:228)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:54)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:351)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:169)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getProviders(Providers.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Invocable.getValueProviders(Invocable.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:873)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.access$000(ComponentModelValidator.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator$1.run(ComponentModelValidator.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)


[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@12421766{/,file:/Users/simeonleyzerzon/kasisto/iapiservice/java/target/iapiservice-0.9.1/,AVAILABLE}{file:/Users/simeonleyzerzon/kasisto/iapiservice/java/target/iapiservice-0.9.1/}
[WARNING] !RequestLog
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@30f54522{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8181}
[INFO] Started @9364ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

I tried reintroducing jdk-10 folder into that location and it seems to fix the JUnit not being able to run problem but recreates the above jetty startup issue.

To summarize:

- With Java 10 present in the list of Mac's JVM's

[image]

the `mvn jetty:run` complains with the ClassNotFound error above but JUnit in STS executes fine:

[image: Tests run with Java 10 present]

- Without Java 10 and with only Java 1.8 present in Mac's JVM location:

[image]

`mvn jetty:run` doesn't produce any ClassNotFound error but JUnit stops working altogether.

**How can I configure STS/Eclipse so that it could execute JUnit tests without paying attention to the absence of Java 10 VM (only java 8) on my Mac?**

**Or maybe there's another solution whereby I could repoint STS to use jdk 10 residing in a non-regular location, i.e. in my home directory, etc.?**

My STS configuration seems to have lots of mentions of jdk-10 expected in that location under /Library/*, however so far its absence there only manifests itself in my inability to execute JUnit tests, perhaps it will rear its head with other Eclipse plugins later down the road as well.

== Installed JREs ====

[image]

Comment: Can you install a fresh OpenJDK 8 and see if that's runnable? It might solve both problems at the same time.

Comment: @nitind why do you think it might solve both problems and what are the steps to do it?

Comment: If your existing Java 8 is missing it Sloan binary (the file not found exception), maybe it's broken and installing a new one will work. The jetty breakage is from packages removed in JDK 9 and newer. And you can download an installer from AdoptOpenJDK.

Comment: @nitind The ClassNotFound actually happens when jdk-10 is present so jdk-8 is not the case of the breakage.  STS seems to have internal dependencies on jdk-10, perhaps it could be switched over to jdk-8?

Comment: can you double check the JRE configuration inside the IDE after removing the JDK10 from your machine? I guess there is still a configuration for JDK10 set that might cause some trouble. Go to the `Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs` to see if there is still your JDK10 install configured.

Comment: @MartinLippert There's indeed a mention of Java SE 10 there (see image I attached) but the IDE defaults to Java 8 one.  Should Java SE 10 be completely removed from that menu??    Also, as I mentioned before, there's plenty of mentions of JDK 10 throughout the STS config (obtained from About STS | Installation Details menu which is, unfortunately, too large for me to post here).  I wonder if those too need/could somehow be changed??

Comment: As I said if there is a JDK10 configured as available JRE in your preferences in STS, I would remove that config from the list of JREs in case you want to get rid of it altogether. However, this is unrelated from the JDK you use to run STS itself on, which you can configure via the `ini` file or the flag at startup, as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @MartinLippert Yes indeed, removal of the JDK10 didn't help.  The below answer is actually mine, it's what I've discovered after further experimentation with command line flags, guess I'm on the right track then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening Eclipse via the following command line specifying the VM explicitly seems to be working allowing the tests to run properly:

```
open -a /Applications/STS.app --args -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -data /Users/abc/cde/workspace -clean -showlocation -vmargs -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

====JUnit Runs=====

[image]

The `-vm` flag seems to force the correct VM into STS's configuration now:

```
*** Date: Tuesday, June 25, 2019 at 10:18:08 AM Eastern Daylight Time

*** Platform Details:

*** System properties:
DRIVERS_LOCATION=/Users/simeonleyzerzon/.dbeaver-drivers
applicationXMI=org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.branding.ui.isOnlyJiraInstalled=false
ds.delayed.keepInstances=true
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.buildId=3.9.5.201807031734-RELEASE-e47
eclipse.commands=-os
macosx
-ws
cocoa
-arch
x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher
/Applications/STS.app/Contents/MacOS/STS
-name
STS
--launcher.library
/Applications/STS.app/Contents/MacOS//../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so
-startup
/Applications/STS.app/Contents/MacOS//../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
-keyring
/Users/simeonleyzerzon/.eclipse_keyring
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
eclipse.home.location=file:/Applications/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/
eclipse.launcher=/Applications/STS.app/Contents/MacOS/STS
eclipse.launcher.name=STS
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=DefaultProfile
eclipse.product=org.springsource.sts.ide
eclipse.startTime=1561458331929
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts.icns
-Xmx1200m
-Djava.class.path=/Applications/STS.app/Contents/MacOS//../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
equinox.init.uuid=true
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=/
ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
gopherProxySet=false
gosh.args=--nointeractive
guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
java.class.path=/Applications/STS.app/Contents/MacOS//../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
java.class.version=52.0
java.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs=/Users/simeonleyzerzon/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/xl/5l5
```

Comment: you should be able to set all those vmargs and the vm itself in the `ini` file if you would like to get rid of that command line, but you have to put the `-vm` argument in the first line of the `ini` file and the path to the java executable in the second line, whereas the vmargs go at the end of that file.